# Iterate over sockets in socket.io v1? "...has no method 'clients'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Before I was able to write something like this:

```
io.sockets.clients().forEach(function (socket) { 
    socket.emit(signal,data);
});
```

Now, I cannot and I get the error `Object #<Namespace> has no method 'clients'`

Is there another way to do this? This is with socket v1.0. (or 1.0.2 I think).

For this I know I can use `io.emit()`, but I would like to iterate over the sockets and perform functions on them in a timer. I can refactor everything into callbacks and set the timer on `io.on()`, but I think I would need to be able to use references (I think javascript would make a copy of the object `socket` in this case instead of referencing it?)

Here's an example

```
setInterval(function(){
    io.sockets.clients().forEach(function (socket) { 
        socket.emit('newMessage',someCalculations());
    });
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my current solution:

```
var socketList = new Array();
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socketList.push(socket);
});

setInterval(function(){
    socketList.forEach(function(){
        socket.emit('newMessage',someCalculations());
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: What about removing on disconnect?

Answer (score 3):

If the info about all the connected sockets has to be send to a single **socket** then

```
    for (var i in io.sockets.connected) {
        var s = io.sockets.connected[i];
        if (socket.id === s.id) {
           continue;
        }
        socket.emit('notify_user_state', s.notify_user_state_data)
    }
```

Comment: it worked for me, thanks @JVE999 should pick this answer

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same problem. Try using:

```
io.sockets.emit('newMessage', someCalculations());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: While this is technically correct according to the sample code in the question, we aren't really iterating through all the connected clients here. We can't emit a different message to every client based on it's ID or some other data, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want find out each connected clients. You can get them from engine.io

```
for (var sid in io.engine.clients) {
  io.to(sid).emit('your message', data);
}
```

`io.engine.clients` is a hash. The key is socket id and the value contain some useful info. e.g. `request`. If you use `passport.socketio`. You can get authed user from that place.