# send private details to each socket with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have 2 players in a multiplayer quiz.

Each client has true answers and false answers.

True answers : `socket.true`

False answers : `socket.false`

I'm increasing each variables answer by answer and finally, after 5 answers, i'm calling finishgame function.

**I want to send a data that contains count of true answers and false answers to each client in `finishgame` function**.

How can I do this ?

If I use `socket.emit` or `socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit` it sends only one socket's data.

For example :

```
Send joe -> joe has 3 true , 2false answers;
Send tim -> tim has 1 true , 4 false answers.
```

But it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new object called `answers` now when a client starts the quiz you create a new `answers` object with the socket.id as index, if you need to add a true or false answer you just edit/create a property for that `answers` object (example `answers[socket.id]['trueAnswers']++`). Now when you want to send true and false answers to the client you can easily read the `answers` object with a supplied socket.id as index from the client you want the data from.

Example:

```
        // Create the object
        Answers = new Object();

        // Client starts the quiz:
        Answers[socket.id] = {
            trueAnswers: 0,
            falseAnswers: 0
        };

        // Client made a correct answer:
        Answers[socket.id].trueAnswers++;

        // Send answers data back that is owned by this socket.id
        io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit(Answers[socket.id]); // Shows 'Object {trueAnswers: 1, falseAnswers: 0}'
```

**Edit**: If you want to send this via a forEach way like you describe I belief this might be what you are looking for:

- Please note that this function is not available anymore in socket.io versions higher then 1.0, it is recommended to keep a array of your socket.id's so you can iterate over them if need be.

  ```
      io.sockets.clients().forEach(function (socket) {
                  // This will go trough all connected sockets
      });
  ```

Comment: i need send this info in same time to different clients so i need a function like foreach in php or .each() in jquery...

Comment: it says typeError: Object #<Namespace> has no method 'clients' @MDG

Comment: @monur00006 I see, they stripped it from socket.io 1.0 version! Maybe there are some (better?) alternatives now. Might be worth researching. If I find anything i'll let you know.

Comment: @monur00006 Okay, seems you need to use the `connected` namespace, check this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563885/socket-io-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-connected-sockets-clients#comment35016975_6967755 not sure if it will work with forEach, seems they changed alot in 1.0

Comment: things getting complicated.. i don't get it but thanks.

Comment: @monur00006 no problem, remember you can still downgrade your node.js version to like 0.8 or something and use the above code (version 1.0 is still new and there are not a lot of examples at the moment)

Comment: i'll try to downgrade. I'm using windows. is there any problem with that ? and thanks for patiance @MDG

Comment: @monur00006 not at all, just use a version manager and you should be fine. For windows and node.js you have for example: https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw and anytime!

Comment: hey @MDG, install node.js v0.8.0 and still same problem :( namespace has no method clients.

Comment: have you made sure to check current node version with `node --version` ?

Comment: yeah i'm sure. tried 5 different versions and each one has another problem.. Which version should i install ? @MDG

Comment: @monur00006 The alternative method seems to be to keep a array of socket.id an iterate over them as need be. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23945018/1531822